# How to know if another application set the largeHeap or not programatically?

Tags: android

I found some game apps use larger memory than the default limit (64MB in Nexus 7).

To achieve that, I assume they set the `android:largeHeap="true"`

In my codes, I want to check if an app set this flag or not. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for `ApplicationInfo` objects [with `FLAG_LARGE_HEAP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#FLAG_LARGE_HEAP). You can get these objects from `PackageManager` (e.g., [via `getApplicationInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)).

Comment: Thanks! May I double check the codes: `int flags = applicationInfo.flags;
        int isLargeHeap = (flags | applicationInfo.FLAG_LARGE_HEAP);` ?

Comment: @JackWM: I think you want `&` and not `|`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6067438/115145