# check all the values of flag bits java Android

Tags: java, android, flags, bit

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067411/checking-flag-bits-java) in order to check the flags for [ApplicationInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) . But then I read [this post](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/what-does-the-applicationinfo-flags-mean.12633/) in order to see if there's a way to get all the values contained in a flag, but I'm a bit confused. Can anyone tell me if there's a way to get all the values and explain it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int flags work this way, you have an integer, say 48, in binary it would be `0011 0000`. this means it contains 2 flags one is `0010 0000` and the other one is `0001 0000`. if you check ApplicationInfo flags you would notice that all the values are powers of 2 (1,2,4,8..) this is because the binary representation of a power of 2 is all zeros and only one 1. so, in order to check what flags the integer 48 contains, you can do it this way (notice the `&` operator, it's a bitwise AND, if you have doubts about it please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)):

```
int value = 48;
int[] possibleFlags = {ApplicationInfo.FLAG_FACTORY_TEST, ApplicationInfo.FLAG_ALLOW_TASK_REPARENTING, ApplicationInfo.FLAG_ALLOW_BACKUP};
String[] flagNames = {"FLAG_FACTORY_TEST", "FLAG_ALLOW_TASK_REPARENTING", "FLAG_ALLOW_BACKUP"};

 for (int i = 0; i < possibleFlags.length; i++) {
    int aFlag = possibleFlags[i];
    String name = flagNames[i];
    boolean hasFlag = (value & aFlag) > 0;
    Log.d("Flags", String.format("flag %s %s", name, hasFlag ? "PRESENT" : "NOT PRESENT"));
}
```

I didn't really understand the approach you're asking about, but another way to check all the flags is to iterate all powers of 2 from 1 to 31 (for 4 bytes integers like java) but you still need to link the numbers to the actual constant, would it be useful? e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    int aFlag = 1 << i;
    boolean hasFlag = (value & aFlag) > 0;
    Log.d("Flags", String.format("flag %s %s", aFlag, hasFlag ? "PRESENT" : "NOT PRESENT"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, lelloman that was the point I understood my question was in fact if there was an aproach like this https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/what-does-the-applicationinfo-flags-mean.12633/

Comment: hum, I added another sample, I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for