# Use an array as a case statement in switch

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to do something like this, i.e., use an array in a switch statement. Is it possible in Java? If it isn't, please explain a possible solution.

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[4];

values[0] = true;
values[1] = false;
values[2] = false;
values[3] = true;

switch (values) {
    case [true, false, true, false]:
        break;
    case [false, false, true, false]:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: I think best is to use an if statement and avoid the switch

Comment: I think that you should ask yourself why your execution should depend on a `boolean` array. Maybe a class could better contain this data with methods that have more semantics (and are more easily tested)? As you have written it, it looks like a future maintenance nightmare.

Comment: in my opinion ALL the above solutions are horrible, because switch/case should't be used with array. anyway, why not hashing?

Comment: Use a loop to set bits on an int based on the array index, and switch off that.

Comment: What you want is called "pattern matching", but you can't do it in Java.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to implement bit flags - see this question: [Implementing a bitfield using java enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346477/implementing-a-bitfield-using-java-enums)

Comment: Make sure you leave well-documented comments describing what is happening in this portion of your code. Even when you yourself come back to it in a week you'll have to read through it a bit to figure out where you want to make changes.

Comment: Assume the array length <= 64, convert array to a `long` representing bitflags, switch against hexadecimal *magic numbers*!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**NO**, simply you cannot.

```
SwitchStatement:
    switch ( Expression ) SwitchBlock
```

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

Comment: This is correct as far as I'm concerned, though some good efforts in the other answers for a good solution.

Comment: Honestly this is the best answer.  I'm not sure the type of gymnastics required to make the original problem work should be encouraged.

Comment: This is really old and I can't even remember what was the initial problem, but looking back at the code it seems that I've done some bad architectural decision. This is why I think this is the correct answer - it is more of a signal of doing something wrong rather than finding a solution.

Answer (score 73):

@sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ is right. But I wanted to add something. Since Java 7, switch statements support Strings, so you could do something with that. **It is really dirty** and I do not recommend, but this works:

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[4];

values[0] = true;
values[1] = false;
values[2] = false;
values[3] = true;

switch (Arrays.toString(values)) {
    case "[true, false, true, false]":
        break;
    case "[false, false, true, false]":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

---

For those concerned about performance: you are right, this is not super fast. This will be compiled into something like this:

```
String temp = Arrays.toString(values)
int hash = temp.hashCode();
switch (hash)
{
    case 0x23fe8da: // Assume this is the hashCode for that
                    // original string, computed at compile-time
        if (temp.equals("[true, false, true, false]"))
        {

        }
        break;
    case 0x281ddaa:
        if (temp.equals("[false, false, true, false]"))
        {

        }
        break;

    default: break;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty neutral +-1. It would be very slow. Also I didn't think you were supposed to *parse* `toString` output in *any* way.

Comment: My initial thought was bitwise operations then this but I don't like it as a solution.

Comment: Creative and terrible at the same time. +1

Comment: Too restricted to the size of the array, if the array as to change in size, what a mess it is to maintain.

Comment: @Bathsheba: You are right, I added some explanation on how terrible the performance is.

Comment: "It is really dirty and I do not recommend" - I think this answer needs to start with that statement, and it needs to be turned into a header. But still, +1 for the dirty, hacky work-around.

Comment: This is hilarious! I think its brilliant, but may get you fired at a job. Great for [my] research code, though!

Comment: Remember, usually code is written once and read many times... This is not very readable (Also up-voted David's comment)

Comment: Pardon me if this sounds rude, but for me, this represents everything that is wrong with Java programming.  The upvotes represent what is wrong with the Java community.

Comment: There is this blasé attitude towards performance.  This type of problem is _very commonly resolved_ with setting bits in an `int` -- yet you convert to and compare _strings_. _In Java_.

Comment: @bobobobo: You are right. I will never write this for my own. This was just a funny piece of code that lies very close to what the OP wanted. I do know that this is horrible, trust me :)

Answer (score 49):

You can't switch on whole arrays. But you *could* convert to a bit set at the expense of some readability of the `switch` itself:

`switch (values[0] + 2 * values[1] + 4 * values[2] + 8 * values[3])`

and use *binary literals* in your case statements: `case 0b0101` is your first one.

Comment: Wow, this is certainly possible, but is that a good solution to the real problem?

Comment: To make this extendable, I'd put it in a loop: `int switchVal = 0; for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) { switchVal += values[i] ? (2 << i) : 0; }` and then switch on the `switchVal` variable.

Comment: And to make the switch more readable/meaningful, consider making each of those binary literals a meaningful constant so you are switching on constants, not binary literals.

Comment: This is basically converting `[true, false, true, false]` to the series of bits `1010`, which can be `switch`ed on, right?  Definitely the way to go IMO.

Comment: I wanted to show a binary example using Lambda in Java SE 8 but wasn't sure if I would get flamed for that. I'll wait until March.

Comment: +1 and @Eric: sure, in spirit this is a great solution to the original problem, although not the generalized version of that problem. The OP has an array of booleans. Converting it to a bitset is not only useful in general, but valuable for this problem. Certainly it could be more legible though (e.g. use a function).

Answer (score 46):

Try this solution:

```
    boolean[] values = new boolean[4];
    values[0] = true;
    values[1] = false;
    values[2] = false;
    values[3] = true;

    if (ArrayUtils.isEquals(values, new boolean[] {true, false, true, false})) {
    ...
    }
    else if (ArrayUtils.isEquals(values, new boolean[] {false, false, true, false})) {
    ...
    }
    else {
    ...
    }
```

See docs [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#isEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: This is a solution really tight up to the size of the array, the moment the array as to change in size, you'll have a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: They named a function `isEquals`??

Comment: @phresnel "is<Something>" is the code pattern for methods that return a boolean value. The method tests if two arrays are equals, so it seems ok to me.

Comment: @drigoangelo Yes, that's true, but the rest of the Java library seems to follow simply `Object.equals(Object)` as in the case of String equality.

Comment: There's no need for apache-commons-lang - just use `java.util.Arrays.equals(arr1,arr2)` from the JDK.

Comment: @drigoangelo: I know I know. But I wonder why they didn't just use `isEqual`, so either `verb adjective` or `verb noun`, instead of `verb verb`. Personally, I just prefer `adjective` for boolean functions, and `verb` for procedures that change state.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau, you'll likely have a maintenance nightmare with this kind of design anyway...

Comment: Doesn't `Arrays.equals` do this without requiring a 3rd-party dependency?

Comment: @phresnel the naming follows the convention. equals can only be used on an instance. ArrayUtils, as all **Utils classes provides static method.

Comment: Coming in fresh looking at Java questions with little Java knowledge but 10yrs+ php background, I nealy puked when I saw this! I respect the code, mind you. I'm not saying this to flame your post. Switch statements are obviously more dynamic in a scripting language but I fail to see why there is no decent support for this   construct in the language. Everything is just way more low-level and it amazes me how people can actually memorize all these complicated hacks to emulate a simple puny switch statement that works pretty nice in php with any size array or int or string etc... My 2 cents.

Comment: @phresnel Yes, isEqual really makes more sense.

Comment: `ArrayUtils.isEquals` can handle multi-dimensional arrays correctly (see docs above), so it's better to have one solution for everything.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you can pass an array to a switch. The catch is that I'm not talking about Java arrays, but a data structure.

> An array is a systematic arrangement of objects, usually in rows and columns.

What you are trying to do is implement a system that recognizes different flags and depending on the flags that are turned on or off you take different actions.

**Example**

A popular implementation of such mechanism is Linux file permissions. Where you have `rwx` as the "array of flags".

If the whole array is true, you'll see `rwx`, which means that you have all the permissions. If you are not allowed to perform any action on a file, the whole array is false, you'll see `---`.

**Implementation**

Guess what, you can think of integers as arrays. An integer is represented by an "array of bits".

```
001 // 1, if on, set x 
010 // 2, if on, set w 
100 // 4, if on, set r
// putting it all together in a single "array" (integer)
111 // 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7
```

That is why the permission `rwx` can be represented as a `7`

Java snippet:

```
class Flags {                                                                    
public static void main(String args[]) {         
        /** 
         * Note the notation "0b", for binary; I'm using it for emphasis.
         * You could just do: 
         * byte flags = 6;
         */                     
        byte flags = 0b110; // 6                     
        switch(flags) {                                                          
            case 0: /* do nothing */ break;                                      
            case 3: /* execute and write */ break;                       
            case 6: System.out.println("read and write\n"); break;         
            case 7: /* grant all permissions */ break;                           
            default:                                                             
                System.out.println("invalid flag\n");           
        }                                                                        
    }                                                                            
}
```

To know more about using a binary format, check this question: [In Java, can I define an integer constant in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/867365/7852)

**Performance**

- Saves memory
- You don't have to do extra processing, switches or any other type of juggling.

C programs that require to be as efficient as possible use this type of mechanism; they use flags represented with single bits.

Answer (score 21):

No, you cannot, however you can replace the above with the following (dirty I admit) code:

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[4];

values[0] = true;
values[1] = false;
values[2] = false;
values[3] = true;

switch(makeSuitableForSwitch(values)) {
   case 1010: 
     break;
   case 10: 
     break;
   default:
     break;
} 

private int makeSuitableForSwitch( boolean[] values) {
    return (values[0]?1:0)*1000+(values[1]?1:0)*100+(values[2]?1:0)*10+(values[3]?1:0);
}
```

Comment: I would put the sum formula into a method instead of directly in the `switch` statement.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it is errr ugly it is wrong: `0010` is interpreted as octal...

Comment: @Alex helper method should be `private` ;) Also it's not a good idea to `return int` since for big arrays this might overflow.

Comment: Had to add parenthesis to the expression due because of the tenary operator precedence.

Comment: I like this, in as much as it seems like it would be easier to maintain vs mammoth if/else statements in the accepted answer

Comment: You can generalize the "makeSuitableForSwitch" to work for any size boolean array

Comment: Also, why `(values[0]?1:0)*1000` if you can do `values[0]?1000:0`?

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to determine if a *set of conditions* is true, I'd use bitwise fields instead.

For example,

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  // These are the options that can be set.
  // They're final so treated as constants.
  static final int A=1<<0, B=1<<1, C=1<<2, D=1<<3 ;

  public static void main(String []args)
  {
    // Now I set my options to have A=true, B=true, C=true, D=false, effectively
    int options = A | B | C ;

    switch( options )
    {
      case (A):
        System.out.println( "just A" ) ;
        break ;
      case (A|B):
        System.out.println( "A|B" ) ;
        break ;
      case (A|B|C): // Final int is what makes this work
        System.out.println( "A|B|C" ) ;
        break ;
      default:
        System.out.println( "unhandled case" ) ;
        break ;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd compute a value based on the sequence of the elements in the boolean array, i.e. `[true, false, true, true]` would evaluate to 1011 and then based on this integer value you can use switch statement.

Comment: Make sure that if you change the length (or order) of the array, it still works, if you want to avoid a rewrite of every 'case' statement. If Java doesn't permit a function call for each 'case', a massive if chain will be required, possibly with an associative array for each alternative case and a function call for each if test.

Answer (score 2):

As of JRE 1.7, you will need to use a hack, I recommend:

- Assume `values.length <= 64`
- Convert values to a `long` representing bitflags
- `Switch` against hexadecimal [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)

**Java Code Hack:**

```
if(values.length > 64)
  throw new IllegalStateException();

long bitflags = 0x0L;

for(int i=0; i< values.length; ++i)
  if(values[i])
    bitflags |= 0x01L << i;

switch(bitflags) {
  case 0xEL: // represents [true,  true,  true, false]
    break;
  case 0xAL: // represents [true,  false, true, false]
    break;
  case 0x2L: // represents [false, false, true, false]
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> This answer is *not Java*, but Haxe because it is possible in it, thanks to pattern matching and has interesting output, which might be useful for you to find a switch that does what you are asking for. Arrays can be matched on fixed length.

I created an demo that compiles to Javascript and Flash. You can see the js-output in the right column.

**Demo:**
http://try.haxe.org/#86314

```
class Test {
  static function main(){

    var array=[true,false,true];

    var result=switch(array){
      case [true,true,false]: "no";
      case [true,false,true]: "yes";
      default:"??";
    }

    #if js
      new js.JQuery("body").html(result);
    #elseif flash
      trace(result);
    #end

    // ouputs: "yes"
  }
}
```

This is the outputted switch, it uses nested switches. If you play with the cases, you see how the js-ouput changes to have a efficient switch.

```
(function () { "use strict";
var Test = function() { };
Test.main = function() {
    var array = [true,false,true,false];
    var result;
    switch(array.length) {
    case 4:
        switch(array[0]) {
        case true:
            switch(array[1]) {
            case false:
                switch(array[2]) {
                case true:
                    switch(array[3]) {
                    case false:
                        result = "no";
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = "??";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "??";
                }
                break;
            default:
                result = "??";
            }
            break;
        case false:
            switch(array[1]) {
            case false:
                switch(array[2]) {
                case true:
                    switch(array[3]) {
                    case false:
                        result = "yes";
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = "??";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "??";
                }
                break;
            default:
                result = "??";
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        result = "??";
    }
    new js.JQuery("body").html(result);
};
var js = {};
var q = window.jQuery;
js.JQuery = q;
Test.main();
})();
```

Another interesting pattern that you can use underscores. a _ pattern matches anything, so case _: is equal to default, which makes you able to do this:

```
var myArray = [1, 6];
var match = switch(myArray) {
    case [2, _]: "0";
    case [_, 6]: "1";
    case []: "2";
    case [_, _, _]: "3";
    case _: "4";
}
trace(match); // 1
```

http://haxe.org/manual/pattern_matching#array-matching

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. The best explain is learn how to use [the switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Switch statements only take ints, chars, bytes, shorts, and enum types.  The "right" way to do it would be either a big if..else block, or to somehow render the array of booleans down to an integer and act accordingly.  Maybe treat it as a bitmask?

Comment: Java switches also take strings

Comment: @Bathsheba For Java7+.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach requiring no imports nor libraries:

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[4];

values[0] = true;
values[1] = false;
values[2] = false;
values[3] = true;

int mask = buildMask(values);

if (areEquals(mask, true, false, true, false)) {
    // ...
} else if (areEquals(mask, false, false, true, false)) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}

private int buildMask(boolean... values) {
    int n = 0;
    for (boolean b : values) {
        n = (n << 1) | (b ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return n;
}

private boolean areEquals(int mask, boolean... values) {
    return mask == buildMask(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at how Groovy implements the isCase() methods in Java, use a simpler version that fits your needs. It's possible to put that in an interface and create a DSL to compare any two object in your application.

```
return isCase(DefaultTypeTransformation.asCollection(caseValue), switchValue);
```

The relevant code is covered in [Lines 877](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L877) through [Lines 982](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L877)

Answer (score 1):

@Todor **Yes, THIS IS POSSIBLE IN JAVA.**

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[4];

values[0] = true;
values[1] = false;
values[2] = false;
values[3] = true;

String values_asString = Arrays.toString(values);
 
switch (values_asString) {
    case "[true, false, true, false]":
        break;
    case "[false, false, true, false]":
        break;
    case "[true, false, false, true]":
        System.out.println("YAAAAAAAAAA GOT IT");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Here I just converted an array to a string format and then matched it in the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use constant int values that represent the boolean state.

If you use **Java 1.7** or above you can use binary literals that are **more readable**.

```
public static final int TRUE_FALSE_TRUE_FALSE = 0b1010;
public static final int FALSE_FALSE_TRUE_FALSE = 0b0010;
```

for **Java 1.6** and below use any other int literals, e.g. hex

```
public static final int TRUE_FALSE_TRUE_FALSE = 0xA;
public static final int FALSE_FALSE_TRUE_FALSE = 0x2;
```

then create a method that converts a boolean array to an integer bitset. E.g.

```
public static int toIntBitSet(boolean...values){
    int bitset = 0;
    for (boolean value : values) {
       bitset = (bitset << 1) | (value ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return bitset;
}
```

Finally use the constants in your switch statement

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false};

int bitset = toIntBitSet(values);

switch (bitset) {
  case TRUE_FALSE_TRUE_FALSE:
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitset));
    break;
  case FALSE_FALSE_TRUE_FALSE:
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitset));
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

**Another approach** might be to use a java `BitSet` and a `Map` that maps to the logic that should be executed depending on the bitset's value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Map<BitSet, Callable<String>> bitSetMap = new HashMap<>();

  bitSetMap.put(bitSetValueOf(true, false, true, false), new TrueFalseTrueFalseCallable());
  bitSetMap.put(bitSetValueOf(false, false, true, false), new FalseFalseTrueFalseCallable());

  boolean[] values = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false};

  BitSet bitset = bitSetValueOf(values);

  Callable<String> callable = bitSetMap.get(bitset);
  if (callable == null) {
    callable = new DefaultCallable();
  }

  String result = callable.call();
  System.out.println(result);
}

public static BitSet bitSetValueOf(boolean... values) {
   BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         bitSet.set(i, values[i]);
      }
   return bitSet;
}
```

and implement your logic

```
class FalseFalseTrueFalseCallable implements Callable<String> {

  @Override
  public String call() throws Exception {
    return "0010";
  }

}

class TrueFalseTrueFalseCallable implements Callable<String> {

  @Override
  public String call() throws Exception {
    return "1010";
  }

}

class DefaultCallable implements Callable<String> {

  @Override
  public String call() throws Exception {
    return "default value";
  }

}
```