# Java Permutation and Combination of boolean flags

Tags: java

I have some boolean variables which will be passed as arguments

```
boolean var1;
boolean var2;
boolean var3;
boolean var4;
```

Depending on these variables, I have to code something like this

```
if (var1 && !var2 && !var3 && !var4) {
  //do something
}
elsif (var1 && var2 && !var3 && !var4) {
  //do something
}
```

.
.
.
and so on.. using all the possible combinations. I can do this using if-else statement. Need to know is there some better approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have 2^4 combinations. You could use a switch.

Comment: This has been partially discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659979/use-an-array-as-a-case-statement-in-switch/20660201

Answer (score 5):

Build a bit pattern out of the four boolean arguments, e.g. `0110` means `var1 = false`, `var2 = true`, `var3 = true` and `var4 = false`.

Then you can use the `switch` construct on the generated numbers.

```
int b = (var1 ? 8 : 0) | (var2 ? 4 : 0) | (var3 ? 2 : 0) | (var4 ? 1 : 0);
switch(b) {
   case 0:
      ...
   case 1:
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better approach. It depends on your code paths. If you really need 2*2*2*2 code paths, you will need to write that code somewhere. Either you make a big if-else block like you suggest, or you find another way to point to an implementation based on your flags (strategy pattern, switch, ..).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm has 2 steps:
**Step 1**. Create N! permutation cases,

**Step 2**. In specific case, using [De Morgan theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
VAR_1 && !VAR_2 && !VAR_3 && ... && !VAR_N  =  VAR_1 AND !OR(VAR_2, VAR_3, ... VAR_N)
```

similar, we have other case:

```
AND(VAR_1, VAR_2) AND !OR(VAR_3, VAR_4, ..., VAR_N)
AND(VAR_1, VAR_2, VAR_3) AND !OR(VAR_4, VAR5, ..., VAR_N)
...
AND(VAR_1, ..., VAR_(N-1)) AND !OR(VAR_N)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reduce number of conditions but can simplify the conditions like this using `Arrays.equals`:

```
boolean var1;
boolean var2;
boolean var3;
boolean var4;

boolean[] varArr = new boolean[]{var1,  var2, var3, var4};

if (Arrays.equals(varArr, new boolean[]{false, false, false, false})) {
    // handle case1
} else if (Arrays.equals(varArr, new boolean[]{true, false, false, false})) {
    // handle case2
} else if (Arrays.equals(varArr, new boolean[]{true, true, false, false})) {
    // handle case3
}
...
...
```